# Display an iteration over a mongodb array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor

I have an array in mongodb collection that houses a bunch of json objects. The structure of which is:

```
{ 
  myField: [
      {key1: val, key2: val, key3: val}, 
      {key1: val, key2: val, key3: val},
      {key1: val, key2: val, key3: val}
  ]
}
```

I want to display the values of each key in the array, such that in the first iteration, all of the key value pairs in the first object in the array get called, then all of the key value pairs in the the second object and so forth. I looked into the docs and saw that $all can be used, but that doesn't really get me the result that I want. I'm using Meteor and blaze, so I'm trying to leverage these tools the best that I can before I have to build something custom.

EDIT:

The output should iterate over a meteor template using blaze. Something like:

```
<template "myTemplate">
 {{#each someHelper}}
   <img src='{{key1}}' id='{{key2}}' class='{{key3}}'
 {{/each}}
</template>
```

I suppose the question can be boiled down to defining the helper function for this each loop. I'm not sure what kind of query I have to make to get the array values.

Comment: I'm a little confused about the desired output. Can you show what the result should look like?

Comment: I tried to elaborate in the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Template helpers can return arrays, so you need only fetch the object and return its `myField` array:

```js
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  someHelper: function() {
    var doc = MyCollection.findOne();
    return doc && doc.myField;
  }
});
```